# .bashrc not reload from script

Tags: bash

Iam newbee in bash scripts . 
I am trying to add a line on .bashrc file :

```
## make python 2.7 default in ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/lib/python/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc  
source ~/.bashrc
```

The source command is not reloading the ~/.bashrc file . (but works if i do it on the prompt )

How I can reload the .bashrc from the script ? 
any help will be more then appreciated .

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Aha! Modern *nix systems *usually* have a system-wide `bashrc` that starts thus:

```
# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.

# To enable the settings / commands in this file for login shells as well,
# this file has to be sourced in /etc/profile.

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
...
stuff follows
```

If you observe the last couple of lines the issue would become obvious.  You are *not* running interactively.  Before sourcing `bashrc` in your script, set `PS1` to an arbitrary value, say:

```
PS1='foobar'
```

and chances are that your `bashrc` would suddenly start *loading* from the script!