# Why am I getting "-bash: 'alias: command not found", but it's there..?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I dont understand why my alias doesnt work, any idea people? I want to use 'pro' as an alias
thanks! ^_^)

this is how my bash-file looks like:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*


# Git branch in prompt.
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
export PS1="\u@\h \W\[\033[32m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "

#******ALIAS FOR TEALEAF_COURSE3**********************

alias pro='cd /Users/yoniPacheko/Documents/ruby/RnR/third_course_0/projects '
```

Comment: What "bash-file" is that and are you sure that it is completely unmodified?

Comment: How are you using the alias?  On the command line or in a script?  What is the path to the `bash-file` that you've mentioned above?

Comment: Does that alias work when you just enter it on the command line itself?

Comment: @trojanfoe hi there this bash is my .bash_profile, and it's modified as u can see :)

Comment: @devnull no that's the thing it doesn't work. It does work if I do a temporary alias though. th epath to this bash is: ~/.bash_profile. Im using it in the command-line

Comment: @Evert u mean a temporary alias? yes it does!

Comment: off the topic: I guess, you should put `parse_git_branch` (which calls `git branch`) out of PS1. Perhaps assign it to a variable & then use that variable in PS1. `PS1` gets evaluated every time it is printed.

Comment: @YoniGeek [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18272440/2235132) answer might help.

Comment: @anishsane good point, I gonna have a look at it...

Comment: @devnull dont get it man, am I doing something wrong. This alias-method should work isn't it?

Comment: @YoniGeek You did not answer the [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094820/why-am-i-getting-bash-alias-command-not-found-but-its-there?noredirect=1#comment29940552_20094820).  How are you using the alias?  In a script?

Comment: @anishsane That's why he's put it in `$PS1`, so that when he changes directory it tells him what git branch he's using.  If he followed your suggestion it wouldn't work as intended.

Comment: Ok, but wouldn't that hurt performance? I haven't used git much. I assumed that `git branch` would query information from server. Apologies for the confusion...

Comment: Did you source the `.bash_profile`? Because `.bash_profile` is only source at login, not at later terminal sessions. So unless you relog, you may want to source `.bash_profile` in every terminal you have open.

Comment: @anishane `git branch` only queries the local repository; the only remote branches it shows are those seen by the most recent `git fetch`.

Comment: @anishsane Yes, 'features' hurt computer performance, but increases human performance ;) Calling *git* has an impact, but as git is distributed the 'server' is local.

Comment: Ok. If it queries only local repo, it should not cause heavy perf hit :-)

Comment: @devnull I did, I think:  Im using it in the command-line in every terminal that I have open.  no script., just like a call

Comment: @Evert "Did you source the .bash_profile?" no, how do u do dat?

Comment: @YoniGeek `source ~/.bash_profile` on your command line.

Comment: @Evert I get this: \u@\h \W\[\033[32m\]\[\033[00m\] $  what's dat?

Comment: @Evert it doesnt work.. though

Comment: In that case, youre `~/.bash_profile` is possibly messed up. You shouldn't get any output. If I take your file as you put it here and source it, I don't get any output. Is this your complete `.bash_profile`?

Comment: @Evert thisis what I get now: ~ source .bash_profile
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
\u@\h \W\[\033[32m\]\[\033[00m\] $ ls

Comment: @YoniGeek Are you sure your shell is a bash? Type `echo $0` in your command line.

Comment: @ArturR.Czechowski hi there! I get this: -zsh  why?

Comment: @YoniGeek so, your shell is obviously zsh not bash.

Comment: @ArturR.Czechowski yeah why? is it a problem? enlighten me pls! I'm very green to this about bash:es

Comment: @ArturR.Czechowski I've installed Oh My ZSH! why? is this problem?

Comment: @ArturR.Czechowski I THINK I GET IT!. The aliases must be in the .zshrc instead. Bu tI getting this problem now: cd:cd:13: no such file or directory: /Users/yoniPacheko/Documents/hej why? I supposed to got directly to the directory 'hej'

Comment: It's sorted! thanks for yr time guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I was looking all the time for the .bash_profile **but I've zsh as a shell**, so I was looking at the wrong place.

The right place is .zshrc, for those that don't run a bash-shell and want to make aliases

But thanks for yr inputs community, I got the picture finally.

:)